# Determine the State given a Lat/Long using Google API in android

Tags: android, maps

Is there a way to determine the State in which a given Lat/Long resides using the Google Api in Android?

thx

Answer (score 1):

As quoo mentionned, you can use reverse geocoding. From quoo's link,

```
Geocoder myLocation = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());   
List<Address> myList = myLocation.getFromLocation(latPoint, lngPoint, 1);
```

You can get then the state by using the `getAdminArea()` method from the `Address` object.

```
myList.get(0).getAdminArea()
```

See more info [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/location/Address.html) of what information you can get from the Address object

Answer (score 0):

I assume you could use reverse geocoding to figure out the state. There was a similar question for android asked here: 
[Android: Reverse geocoding - getFromLocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472313/android-reverse-geocoding-getfromlocation)