# How To search for an address with MapView?

Tags: android

I am creating an app where i need to use map view and allow users to search for an address.
However I do not need the full Maps app functionality. how can I perform a search like in The maps app ( where it auto completes the address) in my own MapVeiw?

Comment: These resources may help you: - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472313/android-reverse-geocoding-getfromlocation