# Google Maps API Street Coordinates

Tags: android, google-maps

I am making an android app. Is it possible to check if a user (given some coordinates) is facing a street and if that street is within 10-20ft away?

If not, is there an open source map which I can "tread" through manually using code/coordinates to see if there is a nearby "street"? I want to make a navigation system for the blind and I need some way to check if the user is standing on the middle of the street.

Thanks,
Rohit

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to read up on the Google Maps Geocoding API:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/

If you're on Android, there's a special [`Geocoder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) class that will call Google Maps for you:

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
```

(Source: [Android: Reverse geocoding - getFromLocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472313/android-reverse-geocoding-getfromlocation))

The catch is that this just going to give the most likely address for the user's current location -- you don't get to specify a fuzz factor or anything like that. Even then, 10-20 ft. should be close enough for this to match.

If this doesn't get you the data you need, you might also want to look at [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/), which is an open maps database. I don't have much experience with it myself, but there's documentation here: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Main_Page

Comment: Is there a way to get an array of coordinates which correspond to the street path? SO I can compare them to the current position?

Comment: You can convert a single address into a lat/long pair ("reverse geocoding"), but the Google APIs won't let you do this for an entire street.