# Finding location name using GPS Location

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, google-api

I am working with android sdk, i have to find location name near by given gps location.

I was using

```
String URL= http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=" + cv.getLatitude() + ","
                        + cv.getLongitude() + "&output=csv"
```

It was giving me collection of location name.
But now google has dropped this service and I am not getting location names.

Kindly suggest me alternate way.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll like [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) class, it does LatLon -> location name and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this thread:

[Android: Reverse geocoding - getFromLocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472313/android-reverse-geocoding-getfromlocation)

You can use the native mapping APIs to do it pretty easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://www.geonames.org.

Here is the documentation of their webservice: http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html

Unless you have a high load, this service should suffice and it is free of charge.