# How to get the current location latitude and longitude in android

Tags: android, android-service, android-location

In my application, I get the current location's latitude and longitude when application is open, but not when the application is closed.

I am using Service class to get the current location latitude and longitude in my application.

Please tell me how to get the current location latitude and longitude even when application is closed

Comment: For those who are looking out for simple implementation to get the current/last known location, check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62761897/3908895

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Before couple of months, I created GPSTracker library to help me to get GPS locations. In case you need to view GPSTracker > getLocation

[Demo](https://github.com/dimitardanailov/androiddemos/blob/master/VarnaLabGeoLocations)

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

**Activity**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView textview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.geo_locations);

        // check if GPS enabled
        GPSTracker gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(this);

        if (gpsTracker.getIsGPSTrackingEnabled())
        {
            String stringLatitude = String.valueOf(gpsTracker.latitude);
            textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.fieldLatitude);
            textview.setText(stringLatitude);

            String stringLongitude = String.valueOf(gpsTracker.longitude);
            textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.fieldLongitude);
            textview.setText(stringLongitude);

            String country = gpsTracker.getCountryName(this);
            textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.fieldCountry);
            textview.setText(country);

            String city = gpsTracker.getLocality(this);
            textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.fieldCity);
            textview.setText(city);

            String postalCode = gpsTracker.getPostalCode(this);
            textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.fieldPostalCode);
            textview.setText(postalCode);

            String addressLine = gpsTracker.getAddressLine(this);
            textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.fieldAddressLine);
            textview.setText(addressLine);
        }
        else
        {
            // can't get location
            // GPS or Network is not enabled
            // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
            gpsTracker.showSettingsAlert();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.varna_lab_geo_locations, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**GPS Tracker**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Create this Class from tutorial : 
 * http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial
 * 
 * For Geocoder read this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472313/android-reverse-geocoding-getfromlocation
 * 
 */

public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    // Get Class Name
    private static String TAG = GPSTracker.class.getName();

    private final Context mContext;

    // flag for GPS Status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    // flag for GPS Tracking is enabled 
    boolean isGPSTrackingEnabled = false;

    Location location;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;

    // How many Geocoder should return our GPSTracker
    int geocoderMaxResults = 1;

    // The minimum distance to change updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    // Store LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER or LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER information
    private String provider_info;

    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    /**
     * Try to get my current location by GPS or Network Provider
     */
    public void getLocation() {

        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            //getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            //getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            // Try to get location if you GPS Service is enabled
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                this.isGPSTrackingEnabled = true;

                Log.d(TAG, "Application use GPS Service");

                /*
                 * This provider determines location using
                 * satellites. Depending on conditions, this provider may take a while to return
                 * a location fix.
                 */

                provider_info = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;

            } else if (isNetworkEnabled) { // Try to get location if you Network Service is enabled
                this.isGPSTrackingEnabled = true;

                Log.d(TAG, "Application use Network State to get GPS coordinates");

                /*
                 * This provider determines location based on
                 * availability of cell tower and WiFi access points. Results are retrieved
                 * by means of a network lookup.
                 */
                provider_info = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;

            } 

            // Application can use GPS or Network Provider
            if (!provider_info.isEmpty()) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    provider_info,
                    MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                    MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, 
                    this
                );

                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider_info);
                    updateGPSCoordinates();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "Impossible to connect to LocationManager", e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Update GPSTracker latitude and longitude
     */
    public void updateGPSCoordinates() {
        if (location != null) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }
    }

    /**
     * GPSTracker latitude getter and setter
     * @return latitude
     */
    public double getLatitude() {
        if (location != null) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * GPSTracker longitude getter and setter
     * @return
     */
    public double getLongitude() {
        if (location != null) {
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * GPSTracker isGPSTrackingEnabled getter.
     * Check GPS/wifi is enabled
     */
    public boolean getIsGPSTrackingEnabled() {

        return this.isGPSTrackingEnabled;
    }

    /**
     * Stop using GPS listener
     * Calling this method will stop using GPS in your app
     */
    public void stopUsingGPS() {
        if (locationManager != null) {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Function to show settings alert dialog
     */
    public void showSettingsAlert() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        //Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle(R.string.GPSAlertDialogTitle);

        //Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage(R.string.GPSAlertDialogMessage);

        //On Pressing Setting button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.action_settings, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        //On pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
            {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Get list of address by latitude and longitude
     * @return null or List<Address>
     */
    public List<Address> getGeocoderAddress(Context context) {
        if (location != null) {

            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.ENGLISH);

            try {
                /**
                 * Geocoder.getFromLocation - Returns an array of Addresses 
                 * that are known to describe the area immediately surrounding the given latitude and longitude.
                 */
                List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, this.geocoderMaxResults);

                return addresses;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(TAG, "Impossible to connect to Geocoder", e);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Try to get AddressLine
     * @return null or addressLine
     */
    public String getAddressLine(Context context) {
        List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);

        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            String addressLine = address.getAddressLine(0);

            return addressLine;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Try to get Locality
     * @return null or locality
     */
    public String getLocality(Context context) {
        List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);

        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            String locality = address.getLocality();

            return locality;
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Try to get Postal Code
     * @return null or postalCode
     */
    public String getPostalCode(Context context) {
        List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);

        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            String postalCode = address.getPostalCode();

            return postalCode;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Try to get CountryName
     * @return null or postalCode
     */
    public String getCountryName(Context context) {
        List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);
        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            String countryName = address.getCountryName();

            return countryName;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

### Note

If the method / answer doesn't work. You need to use the official Google Provider: 
[FusedLocationProviderApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi#getLastLocation(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient)).

Article: [Getting the Last Known Location](http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html)

Comment: GpsTracker class crashes in 4.2 version, but it works fine in 2.3

Comment: Hi Uday, Thank you for report I will try to update my code. GpsTracker after 2 months will have first birthday :) 

Next days I will to fix this issue.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. But the problem is that i am getting "Enable GPS dialog" even after i have enabled the Location service. How we can fix this problem?

Comment: Your Manifest have these configurations: 

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

Can you try with another device ?

Comment: it is showing error for canGetLocation() for this condition if (gpsTracker.canGetLocation())

Comment: Hello @Navakanth thank you very much for feedback. Today I implement a new version. Please use gpsTracker.getIsGPSTrackingEnabled() instead gpsTracker.canGetLocation()

Comment: getting 0 valu and null value

Comment: @HeminaShah try with FusedLocationProviderApi
: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi#getLastLocation(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient)

Comment: if googleplayservice not login then it's not working.

Comment: Yes I know. Before 12 months we had same issue and our solution to switch to FusedLocationProviderApi. Google changing a lot of things in this direction and my implementation for some cases not working.

Comment: can you share example in fusedlocation and without googleAPI

Comment: What do you mean without GoogleAPI ? You need to have Fusedlocation API.

Comment: Will these text views update automatically when location info updates?

Comment: No, you should add onLocationChanged method. Please read this guide -> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html

Comment: address, city is coming as null

Comment: @TusharGogna please share more details: device and operation system.

Comment: every time lat:0.0,lon:0.0

Comment: GPS is enabled ? Please give us more details about Operating System and Device.

Comment: os is android 6.0.1,gps is enabled,moto g4 plus if gps is on and install and run the app am getting correct coordinates,if i turn off gps then asking to enable gps then enabled and open the app at that time 0.0 not refeclted multiple times open and close and kll the app in background and open then only location details coming

Comment: You need to use the official Google Provider: FusedLocationProviderApi

Comment: @d.danailov solve this problem i cannot understand whats wrong in this code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43950835/cant-get-user-gps-location-in-background-in-android

Comment: @d.danailov I have tried the Geocoder to get the address from the latitude and longitude, but it doesn't provides me with the exact address of my current location, it gives the address of a nearby street or place

Comment: @SamarthKejriwal `Geocoder` is trying to receive `latitude` and `longitude` if `GPS` is enable and if that is not possible `Geocoder` is *using* `NetworkData` (`Wifi` or `3G`). The boolean variable is: `isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);` Please provide me more information why your program can't access the `GPS_PROVIDER`.

Comment: See my application initially asks for the permission of accesing location, then i tap on "Allow" and after that when i fetch the address from my current latitude and longitude then it gives me different address everytime I open the application for the same longitude and latitude

Comment: @SamarthKejriwal could you give me more details about Hardware and Android Version ? If `Geocoder ` doesn't work my recommendations is FusedLocationProviderApi

Comment: @d.danailov right now I am using the Google Maps geocoding API. but still, I am facing the same problem in getting the exact address of my location. and I have used FusedLocationProviderApi, that gives me the updated Lat. and Long, but it doesn't provides the address of the current location.

Comment: Hi @SamarthKejriwal could you create a small demo of your project because to be frankly I can't understand the problem and how to help you.

Comment: @SamarthKejriwal Let's to be Github ?

Comment: Here is my project link : Please look at this MAinActivity.java. This is used to fetch the location : https://github.com/samarth220194/Nearby-Restaurants-Tracking/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/samarthkejriwal/easyroads/MainActivity.java

Comment: every time lat=0.0,long=0.0, what to do please help.

Comment: @RayVaniya please share with me more about Android OS and Android Device.

Comment: the problem is solved, problem is not in the code, actually i forget to register `GPSTracker` in `AndroidManifest` @d.danailov

Comment: @D.Danailov every time Lat=0.0,long=0.0,this code i used in the fragment instead of activity, My Android version is 7.0,GPS is also enabled, Samsung J7, What to do pls Help me

Answer (score 59):

> ## IMPORTANT:
>
> Please notice this solution is from 2015 might be too old and deprecated.

---

None of the above worked for me so I made a tutorial and wrote it for myself since I lost many hours trying to implement this. Hope this helps someone:

## How to use Google Play Services **LOCATION API** to get current latitude & longitude

1) Add to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file the `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` & `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`:

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example.appname" >

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

        <application...
```

2) Go to `app/build.gradle`file and add the following dependency (**make sure to use the latest available version**):

```
    dependencies {
        //IMPORTANT: make sure to use the newest version. 11.0.1 is old AF
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.1
    }
```

3) In your activity implement the following:

```
    import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;

    public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
            ConnectionCallbacks,
            OnConnectionFailedListener,
            LocationListener {

        //Define a request code to send to Google Play services
        private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
        private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
        private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
        private double currentLatitude;
        private double currentLongitude;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    // The next two lines tell the new client that “this” current class will handle connection stuff
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    //fourth line adds the LocationServices API endpoint from GooglePlayServices
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();

            // Create the LocationRequest object
            mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                    .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                    .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
                    .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds

        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            //Now lets connect to the API
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            Log.v(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "onPause()");

            //Disconnect from API onPause()
            if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
                mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            }


        }

        /**
         * If connected get lat and long
         * 
         */
        @Override
        public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
            Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

            if (location == null) {
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

            } else {
                //If everything went fine lets get latitude and longitude
                currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
                currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();

                Toast.makeText(this, currentLatitude + " WORKS " + currentLongitude + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {}

        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
            /*
             * Google Play services can resolve some errors it detects.
             * If the error has a resolution, try sending an Intent to
             * start a Google Play services activity that can resolve
             * error.
             */
            if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
                try {
                    // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
                    connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
                    /*
                     * Thrown if Google Play services canceled the original
                     * PendingIntent
                     */
                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                    // Log the error
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                /*
                 * If no resolution is available, display a dialog to the
                 * user with the error.
                 */
                Log.e("Error", "Location services connection failed with code " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
            }
        }

        /**
         * If locationChanges change lat and long
         * 
         * 
         * @param location
         */
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
            currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();

            Toast.makeText(this, currentLatitude + " WORKS " + currentLongitude + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
```

### If you need more info just go to:

[The Beginner’s Guide to Location in Android](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-location-android)

Note: This doesn't seem to work in the emulator but works just fine on a device

Comment: It is now 8.4.0: `compile: com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0`

Comment: This is great. Very simple answer, and worked like a charm. It's crazy how many examples of trying to simply display a location I had to go through in order to just spit out the latitude and longitude. Great and simple answer, thanks again!

Comment: @VincentRusso, my pleasure :)

Comment: Thaks! is saw lot of examples its one very easy to understand the code.

Comment: This works perfectly fine! But can I run this in back ground?

Comment: Have not try it but sound worth a shot, tired of the GPSTracker class

Comment: Thank You so much this is working quite and giving lat and long.

Comment: I am getting an error and my app is crashing. It says: `java.lang.SecurityException: Client must have ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to request PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY locations.`

Comment: It is now  `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.0'`

Comment: @CodingMcCodington Thanks for the answer :) It was very helpful :)

Comment: Thank you , It works fine and now it is:
    `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.1'`

Comment: Using this code how I can get latitude and longitude when the app in the background?

Comment: These are working for me now: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+',  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4',
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'

Comment: I will give you 10000000000 votes if possible saved my time it's working for me

Answer (score 6):

Use Location Listener Method

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
Double lat = loc.getLatitude();
Double lng = loc.getLongitude();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use following class as service class to run your application in background

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyService extends Service {

    private GPSTracker gpsTracker;
    private Handler handler= new Handler();
    private Timer timer = new Timer();
    private Distance pastDistance = new Distance();
     private Distance currentDistance = new Distance();
    public static double DISTANCE;
    boolean flag = true ;
    private double totalDistance ;
    @Override
    @Deprecated
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(HomeFragment.HOMECONTEXT);
        TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if(flag){
                            pastDistance.setLatitude(gpsTracker.getLocation().getLatitude());
                            pastDistance.setLongitude(gpsTracker.getLocation().getLongitude());
                            flag = false;
                        }else{
                            currentDistance.setLatitude(gpsTracker.getLocation().getLatitude());
                            currentDistance.setLongitude(gpsTracker.getLocation().getLongitude());
                            flag = comapre_LatitudeLongitude();
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(HomeFragment.HOMECONTEXT, "latitude:"+gpsTracker.getLocation().getLatitude(), 4000).show();

                    }
                });


            }
        };

        timer.schedule(timerTask,0, 5000);

    }

    private double distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
          double theta = lon1 - lon2;
          double dist = Math.sin(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.sin(deg2rad(lat2)) + Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(theta));
          dist = Math.acos(dist);
          dist = rad2deg(dist);
          dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
           return (dist);
        }

       private double deg2rad(double deg) {
          return (deg * Math.PI / 180.0);
        }
       private double rad2deg(double rad) {
          return (rad * 180.0 / Math.PI);
   }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        return null;
    }



    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();
        System.out.println("--------------------------------onDestroy -stop service ");
        timer.cancel();
        DISTANCE = totalDistance ;
    }
    public boolean comapre_LatitudeLongitude(){

        if(pastDistance.getLatitude() == currentDistance.getLatitude() && pastDistance.getLongitude() == currentDistance.getLongitude()){
            return false;
        }else{

            final double distance = distance(pastDistance.getLatitude(),pastDistance.getLongitude(),currentDistance.getLatitude(),currentDistance.getLongitude());
            System.out.println("Distance in mile :"+distance);
            handler.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    float kilometer=1.609344f;

                    totalDistance = totalDistance +  distance * kilometer;
                    DISTANCE = totalDistance;
                    //Toast.makeText(HomeFragment.HOMECONTEXT, "distance in km:"+DISTANCE, 4000).show();

                }
            });

            return true;
        }

    }

}
```

Add One  another class to get location

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class GPSTracker implements LocationListener {
private final Context mContext;
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
boolean canGetLocation = false;
Location location = null; 
double latitude; 
double longitude; 

private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

protected LocationManager locationManager;
private Location m_Location;
 public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    m_Location = getLocation();
    System.out.println("location Latitude:"+m_Location.getLatitude());
    System.out.println("location Longitude:"+m_Location.getLongitude());
    System.out.println("getLocation():"+getLocation());
    }

public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
        } 
        else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network Enabled");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}

public void stopUsingGPS() {
    if (locationManager != null) {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }
}

public double getLatitude() {
    if (location != null) {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    return latitude;
}

public double getLongitude() {
    if (location != null) {
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    return longitude;
}

public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


}
```

// --------------Distance.java

```
 public class Distance  {
    private double latitude ;
    private double longitude;
        public double getLatitude() {
            return latitude;
        }
        public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
            this.latitude = latitude;
        }
        public double getLongitude() {
            return longitude;
        }
        public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
            this.longitude = longitude;
        }



}
```

Comment: Can u have sample demo application for this piece of code with settings.. It will be really helpful

Answer (score 2):

**The activity should implements LocationListener

In onCreate(), write the following code **

```
  Boolean network = haveNetworkConnection();
    Log.e("network", "---------->" + network);
    if (!network) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Network is not available",
                3000).show();

    }

    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap);
    googleMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 30000, 0, this);




        if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
            && !locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {



         TextView title = new TextView(context);
         title.setText("Location Services Not Active");
            title.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            title.setPadding(10, 15, 15, 10);
            title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            title.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            title.setTextSize(22);


            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);




        builder.setCustomTitle(title);


        // builder.setTitle("Location Services Not Active");
        builder.setMessage("Please enable Location Services and GPS");

        builder.setPositiveButton("Turn on",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface,
                            int i) {
                        // Show location settings when the user acknowledges
                        // the alert dialog
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);

                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                });

        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        builder.show();

    }

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);

    if (location == null) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS signal not found",
                3000).show();
    }
    if (location != null) {
        Log.e("locatin", "location--" + location);

        Log.e("latitude at beginning",
                "@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@" + location.getLatitude());
        onLocationChanged(location);
    }
```

**Write a method haveNetworkConnection**

```
private boolean haveNetworkConnection() {
    boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
    boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
    for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                haveConnectedWifi = true;
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                haveConnectedMobile = true;
    }
    return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;
}



@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {


    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latLng)
            .title("Current LOC")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));

    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(17));


}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is Android Location library you can 
find your current location without using Google account or subscription.

Find this link and download repository

https://github.com/mrmans0n/smart-location-lib

Take care and Enjoy...

Answer (score 1):

try this, hope it will help you to get the current location, every time the location changes.

```
public class MyClass implements LocationListener {
    double currentLatitude, currentLongitude;

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
    }
}
```

Comment: @deHaar I'm not getting how to call that. if i use ` new MyClass()` will it call that. or do i need to something else. Please tell me

Comment: @shiv Sorry, I cannot tell you because this isn't my answer, I just edited the code to make it be displayed in a neat way... Ask fazeel zama, he posted this answer.

Answer (score 0):

for this porous , you can use flowing code :

```
public class GetLocationActivity extends BaseActivity {
//for getting update of location
FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationClient;
//new callback result requesting in activity
ActivityResultLauncher<String[]> locationPermissionRequest =
        registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts
                        .RequestMultiplePermissions(), result -> {
                    Boolean fineLocationGranted = result.get(
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
                    Boolean coarseLocationGranted = result.get(
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
                    if (fineLocationGranted != null && fineLocationGranted) {
                        // Precise location access granted.
                        if (coarseLocationGranted != null && coarseLocationGranted) {
                            // Only approximate location access granted.
                            //chek is Gps is On or Off and ask from user to enable is
                            checkGPS();
                        }
                    } else {
                        // No location access granted.
                        //show toast for errors
                    }
                }
        );

private void checkGPS() {
//create call for checking gps sensor
    LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();

    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(locationRequest);

    SettingsClient settingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this);
    Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task = settingsClient.checkLocationSettings(builder.build());

    task.addOnSuccessListener(this, locationSettingsResponse -> {
        Log.d("GPS_main", "OnSuccess");
        // GPS is ON
    });

    task.addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull final Exception e) {
            Log.d("GPS_main", "GPS off");
          
            // GPS off
            if (e instanceof ResolvableApiException) {
                ResolvableApiException resolvable = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                try {
                    resolvable.startResolutionForResult(GetLocationActivity.this, 1);
                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}




@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   
    fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

    //location button
    findViewById(R.id.lastLocationFab).setOnClickListener(view -> getPermission());
   
}

private void getPermission() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        //call request
        locationPermissionRequest.launch(new String[]{
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION});

    } else {
        fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(LocationRequest.create()
                        .setInterval(36000).setFastestInterval(36000)
                        .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY)
                        .setMaxWaitTime(1000),
                getLocationCallback(), Looper.myLooper());
        getCurrentLocation();
    }
}

private LocationCallback getLocationCallback() {
    return new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
            List<Location> locationList = locationResult.getLocations();
            if (locationList.size() > 0) {
                //The last location in the list is the newest
                Location location = locationList.get(locationList.size() - 1);

            
                //Place current location marker
              
            }
        }

        
    };
}


public void getCurrentLocation() {
    fusedLocationClient.getCurrentLocation(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY, new CancellationToken() {
        @Override
        public boolean isCancellationRequested() {
            return false;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public CancellationToken onCanceledRequested(@NonNull OnTokenCanceledListener onTokenCanceledListener) {
            return null;
        }
    }).addOnSuccessListener(this, location -> {
        // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
        if (location != null) {
            LatLng myLoc = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
           
        }
    });

  }
```