# Can't get location and email using Facebook API

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api

In my Android application I developed this code to login with my account and get user property like name, location and email. The problem is I can get the name, but I can't get the email and the location. When I tried my code without try catch the application crush and my log point in `getproperty("email")` and `getlocation()`. When I use the try. The application work but there is no email or location.

```
public class Share extends Fragment {private static final String TAG ="Share";private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
private View otherView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // To maintain FB Login session
        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.share, container, false);
        // Looks for Login button
        LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
        authButton.setFragment(this);
        // Set View that should be visible after log-in invisible initially
        otherView = view.findViewById(R.id.other_views);
        otherView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_likes", "user_status","email","user_birthday"));
        return view;
    }

    // Called when session changes
    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };

    // When session is changed, this method is called from callback method
    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state,Exception exception) {
        final TextView name = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.name);
        final TextView mail = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.mail);
        final TextView location = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.location);
        final TextView locale   = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.locale);
        final TextView info = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.msginfo);
        final LinearLayout views= (LinearLayout)getView().findViewById(R.id.other_views);

        if (state.isOpened()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
            // make request to the /me API to get Graph user
            views.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            info.setText("You can now share images in facebook ");
            Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                // callback after Graph API response with user
                // object
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                    if (user != null) {
                        try {
                            // Set view visibility to true
                            otherView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            // Set User name
                            name.setText("Hello " + user.getName());
                            // Set Email
                            mail.setText("Your Email: " + user.getProperty("email").toString());
                            locale.setText("Locale: " + user.getProperty("locale").toString());
                            location.setText("Your Current Location: " + user.getLocation().getProperty("name").toString());

                        }
                        catch(Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).executeAsync();
        } else if (state.isClosed()) {
            views.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            info.setText("If you want to share images in Facebook, please Login");

            Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
            otherView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.i(TAG, "OnActivityResult...");
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        uiHelper.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you asked for permissions?

Comment: i need just the internet permission.i can login and have my image and my username so i don't think that the problem was in the permission.

Comment: Facebook permissions I am talking about!

Comment: ah yes i get my ID and this is what i put in my manifest:   <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity">
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id"/>

Comment: That is your ID, I am not talking about that. Check this in your code `//authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_likes", "user_status","email","user_birthday"));`

Comment: OMG i think this is the problem, i set the permission for publish and i forget for reading. thank you

Comment: sorry , it's still not working. i have this message. some of permission are not allowed

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The issue is that you have not asked for permissions:

```
authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_likes", "user_status","email","user_birthday"));
```

However, you are using an older Facebook SDK, while the [newest SDK is 4.0.+](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/4.0/). Below, I will give you a full sample code for Facebook login, based on the newest API. Keep in mind that you first have to add your application in `developers.facebook` as the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.3) mentions out.

```
public class LoginActivity extends ActionBarActivity{

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, data);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.loginFaceBook_button);
    List<String> permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList("user_photos", "email", "user_birthday", "public_profile");
    loginButton.setReadPermissions(permissionNeeds);

    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult)
        {
            System.out.println("onSuccess");
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest
                    (loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response)
                        {
                            // Application code
                            Log.v("LoginActivity", response.toString());
                            //System.out.println("Check: " + response.toString());
                            try
                            {
                                String id = object.getString("id");
                                String name = object.getString("name");
                                String email = object.getString("email");
                                String gender = object.getString("gender");
                                String birthday = object.getString("birthday");
                                System.out.println(id + ", " + name + ", " + email + ", " + gender + ", " + birthday);
                            }
                            catch (JSONException e)
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender, birthday");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel()
        {
            System.out.println("onCancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception)
        {
            System.out.println("onError");
            Log.v("LoginActivity", exception.getCause().toString());
        }
    });
  }
}
```

If you want to use `Fragment` instead of `ActionBarActivity`, the just add `loginButton.setFragment(this);` right after your permission line.

manifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<application
    <!-- your other attrs..-->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/app_id"/> <!-- Get this one from developers.facebook -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
        android:label="@string/app_name"/>
```

You will need to add to your application a **hash key** too. Here is a way to do this with code:

```
try
{
    //paste Your package name at the first parameter
    PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("PUT_YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME_HERE",
            PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
    for (android.content.pm.Signature signature : info.signatures)
    {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
        String sign = Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        Log.e("MY KEY HASH:", sign);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),sign,     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
{
}
catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
{
}
```

After it prints you out the hash key, you copy paste it to your `facebook.developer` account, where your project is located.

In grandle, you should add `jcenter` in `repositories` and also add `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'` in `dependecies`.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}
allprojects 
{
repositories {
    jcenter()
    /*more project attrs..*/
  }
}
```

And the other grandle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
}
```

Edit:

In order to track the user's location, you will need a GPS Tracker, something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17519198/how-to-get-the-current-location-latitude-and-longitude-in-android). `"user_location"` permission does not return a `lon, lat`, but a [Page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/) object, which I think is not what you want. So, your permissions should be `List<String> permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList("user_photos", "email", "user_birthday", "public_profile");` and now you should be able to retrieve user's email

Comment: thank you. i move up to the newest facebook sdk, but i have problem with build.gradle can you send me your gradle please?

Comment: @user3921905 I did add the build.grandle files. `com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'` should do the job here. Let me know if that fixed your problem

Comment: Also, [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started) is the full documentation about manifest and grandle set up.

Comment: i tried your code but i don't know why my email always return null. and when i make username.setText(name), there is nothing in textview, but i can see the result when i debug the code?

Comment: @user3921905 so you can see all the results in the console, but you have a problem in setting it to `textview`? Then make sure you have a reference on your textview like: `TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mTextView)`. Since code runs, that would be the only case.. Also, if you are running code to a `fragment`, make sure to have this line of code after the permission line: `loginButton.setFragment(this);` After having the reference, then write: `username.setText(String.valueOf(name))`

Comment: i reload the application and it work but the email always null i don't know why

Comment: paste your code somewhere like [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/), so I can check it

Comment: this is the link for the code (i can't get the email and location) http://pastebin.com/HC5Ssz0j

Comment: @user3921905 You should recieve user's current location by using `GPS`, because `user_location` does not return `lon,lat` object. Check my edit. You will need to remove `user_location` from your permissions and location variable as well, and code should run :)

Comment: thank you again for your time. i will search again to get the email.

Comment: @Try_me I am trying to post the picture using my app on user timeline. I am using sample code and It is using the publis_actions. Through this I am successfully posting image on my wall using my app. But it is not showing to others I have checked if it is set to only me , but No it is set to Public but it still not showing up to others. What should I do . '?

Comment: @ghosttalker please create a `new question` with your code and link it here so I can check in detail what's going on.

Comment: this is my exact problem 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29667072/android-facebook-sdk-posting-photo-is-public-but-not-showing-to-friends

Comment: Yes. Technology evolves.