# get userprofile after login with facebook sdk 4.0.1 in next activity android

Tags: android, facebook

My application allows the user to connect with Facebook. I want to get `userprofile` information after login with Facebook (using Facebook SDK 4.0.1). I think that I should use `aynctask` to get it but I don't know how.

```
loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult)
        {
            System.out.println("onSuccess");
            msginfo.setText("You can now share image on facebook");
            otherview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest
                    (loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response)
                        {
                            // Application code
                            Log.v("LoginActivity", response.toString());
                            //System.out.println("Check: " + response.toString());
                            try
                            {
                                String id = object.getString("id");
                                idT.setText(object.getString("id"));
                                ppv.setProfileId(object.getString("id"));
                                nameT.setText(object.getString("name"));
                                emailT.setText(object.getString("email"));
                                locationT.setText(object.getString("address"));

                                String name = object.getString("name");
                                String email = object.getString("email");
                                String gender = object.getString("gender");
                                String birthday = object.getString("birthday");
                                // String location = object.getString("location");
                                // String location = object.getString("user_location");
                                // String location = object.getString("address");




                                System.out.println(id + ", " + name + ", " + email + ", " + gender + ", " + birthday);
                                // locationT.setText(location);

                            }
                            catch (JSONException e)
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender, birthday,link");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancel()
        {
            System.out.println("onCancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception)
        {
            System.out.println("onError");
            Log.v("LoginActivity", exception.getCause().toString());
        }
    });
```

And I can get the profile informations in the current activity but not in the next one.

Comment: Can you please explain more.What do you want?

Comment: Create gatter and setter method for all data in an class.. and set the value and get the value in other activity ..

Comment: @Soham i want when the user connect with facebook he can see his information in the next activity(username, profileimage).

Comment: @Destro i already tried this method it work but it's not the best solution because i can't save the imageprofile and get it

Comment: Image are also send through bite code 1 activity to another activity..

Comment: Where is your Intent ? @juniordevelopper

Comment: @Soham i just post the loginbutton, i already resolved it i used the Profiletracker to get the user informations. but i can't get the userimage because i'm using an imageview not a profilepictureview

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing permissions

```
parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender,picture,birthday");
```

And then you can easily get profile pic

```
object.getJSONObject("picture").getJSONObject("data").getString("url");
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you for your help but when i use `profilepictureview.               setProfileId(Profile.getCurrentProfile().getId());` i get the image but when i use `imageview                  .setImageBitmap(getFacebookProfilePicture(Profile.getCurrentProfile().getId()));` or  `imageview                    .setImageURI(Profile.getCurrentProfile().getProfilePictureUri(135,135));`
i get null, i don't know why i spend the whole day triying without result

Comment: I don'tthink you will get url by using Profile.getCurrentProfile().getProfilePictureUri(135,135).Here is where I gave the full solution you can check that link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29634660/facebook-sdk-4-0-1-login-without-login-button/29693694#29693694