# NoClassDefFoundError with facebook login

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I've updated facebook sdk to version  4.0 and now when I'm trying build project I have this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.LoggingBehavior[]
            at com.facebook.FacebookSdk.<clinit>(FacebookSdk.java:62)
            at pl.essentialapps.superplanner.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:140)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Anyone could help?

EDIT: my Actvity on create method

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        if (isLogged()) {
            startActivityAfterLogin();
            finish();
        } else {
            FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
            callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
            mBtnFacebook = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.btnFacebook);
            mBtnFacebook.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));

            setListeners();
            setFont();
            initStartAnimation();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you haven't initialized Facebook sdk. Post your activity class

Comment: @Soham I've added oncreate method, I think it's most important part

Comment: Ok. It's showing error at pl.essentialapps.superplanner.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:140)   What was in that line ?

Comment: @Soham FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

Comment: Ok I am not able to find the root cause but you can check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29634660/facebook-sdk-4-0-1-login-without-login-button/29693694#29693694

Comment: What's your build system? Are you using Gradle, and have a maven dependency, or did you import the Facebook SDK as code? If you did the latter, it seems like you didn't bring in the LoggingBehavior class.