# Facebook SDK invalid Hash Key

Tags: android, facebook, hash, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm writing an android application with my friend. In the application we use Facebook SDK and a login button. We already setup the hash key using the code similar to what facebook suggests [Code](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#troubleshooting) in the app profile in facebook. We also wrote the key under *Settings -> Key Hashes*. When testing the login on real device , if the native facebook app is using my friends account our application can login , but if i use my account I get the error :

> Invalid key hash . The key hash XXXXXXXXX.... doesn't not match any stored key hashes . configure your app key hashes at ......

We checked in the application profile and my account is also written there with Admin privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this code in your application and you will have the Hash Key:

```
try
{
    //paste Your package name at the first parameter
    PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("PUT_YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME_HERE",
            PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
    for (android.content.pm.Signature signature : info.signatures)
    {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
        String sign = Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        Log.e("MY KEY HASH:", sign);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), sign, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
{
}
catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
{
}
```

For a full facebook login example [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29605236/login-facebook-getlocation-and-email/29605975#29605975).

Since you are logging from other devices, you should enable your app in the `facebook console`. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329250/the-developers-of-this-app-have-not-set-up-this-app-properly-for-facebook-login) to see how.

Comment: but this is the code that im using , check the link in the post i wrote .

Comment: Are you sure you have edited your facebook developer console and saved your settings?

Comment: yeah , because the app works if i try with my friends facebook accout , i mean on my phone if i use facebook native application with my friends account

Comment: Please enable your application if you haven't yet. I edited my answer.

Comment: If the above does not fix your problem, you should delete your application from the `facebook console` and do the process from the begining as it might have bugged out.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using the correct password as keytool apparently doesn't reject an incorrect one and will generate an incorrect hash. The default keystore password is `android`