# Facebook Sdk Has Not Been Initialized FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize()

Tags: android, react-native, facebook-login, android-facebook, fbsdk

Hey I know this was asked before, but none of the solutions seem to help. I'm using first time Facebook SDK in my application.

What I've tried:

I had tried most of the things found on **Internet** but did not get anything regarding this.

Here is my MainActivity.java:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
   } 
}
```

Here is My Activitymain.xml:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

 <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/connectWithFbButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="  connect_with_facebook" /> 
</LinearLayout>
```

see my **Logcat**:

```
 05-13 16:30:39.332: E/AndroidRuntime(10264): Caused by: The SDK has not been initialized, make sure to call FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize() first.
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You have to use `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());` **before** `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` as [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/) states out. In case you need a complete facebook login example, [check this one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29605236/cant-get-location-and-email-using-facebook-api/29605975#29605975).

Comment: When I use "FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());", I get the error: "Cannot resolve symbol 'FacebookSdk'". I get the same error if I try "import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;". I am using Facebook SDK 3.23.1. How can I initialize SDK in v3.23.1? Your solution only seems to work for Facebook SDK 4.x.

Comment: @JaimeMontoya I really recommend you to use the [newest version of the SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/).

Comment: Ideally I should definitely do that. However, in the short-term I am trying to use Facebook SDK v3.23.1 because upgrading to SDK 4.x would require major changes in the source code that are not realistically applicable overnight. How could I initialize Facebook SDK in v3.23.1? I have been examining https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.23/ and I wonder if it is even possible to initialize it. If not, can I still implement Facebook App Events on Android without initializing SDK v3.23.1?

Comment: Facebook Analytics is working for me using SDK v3.23.1. I am simply using the AppEventsLogger class as explained at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.23.1/class/AppEventsLogger/. I did not have to initialize Facebook SDK because I could not even do that. SDK v3.23.1 does not include a the sdkInitialize() method.

Answer (score 59):

## Problem

While integrating Android SDK for a react-native project, I had finished the [Android with React Native v0.30+ Project Configuration](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native/configure-android-current) guide, and ran `react-native run-android` and then got this screen:

[image]

I learned that `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize` is deprecated. [see here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/current/facebook/com/facebook/facebooksdk.html/#sdkinitialize-context-int-)

After some searching, I realized that the guide did not contain the steps to add the Facebook App ID for my app.

## Solution

1. Open `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` file and look in the `<application>` tag to confirm that this `meta-data` tag exists:

   ```
   <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
             android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
   ```
2. Open `android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml` file and confirm that this there is a "facebook_app_id" string tag with your app id as the value:

   ```
   <string name="facebook_app_id">YOUR_APP_ID_HERE</string>
   ```
3. Run `react-native run-android`.

These are the steps that worked for me.

Comment: Run `react-native run-android` works but still have problem when running inside Android Studio, I think React Native has the help from Buck

Comment: what do you mean by app id?

Comment: In addition, we also need to add com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken in meta and string.

Answer (score 40):

For SDK v13.+ you must add **App ID** and **Client Token**.

1. Open the /app/res/values/strings.xml file in your app project and add:

```
<string name="facebook_app_id">1234</string>
<string name="facebook_client_token">56789</string>
```

2. Open the /app/manifests/AndroidManifest.xml file in your app project and add:

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" ...>
    ...
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken" android:value="@string/facebook_client_token"/>
    ...
</application>
```

You can find your Client Token in your FB Developer account:

App > Dashboard > Settings > Advanced > Security > Client token.

Comment: What to do if the Client token is empty in the dashboard ?

Comment: This is the correct answer for new versions. Client Token is required. Thank you.

Comment: @BugsBunnyBR same is showing for me. DId you reset the client token from the console?

Comment: yeah, I asked the person in charge of the account to reset it for me.

Comment: Just to help clarify if it appears blank having "Developer" level permissions with access to the console is not enough to generate an ID. You'll need to ask an "Administrator" (visible under Roles -> Roles) to reset it for you.

Once they've reset as a "Developer" you should be able to retrieve the key from the console.

Answer (score 32):

You don't need to use FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize anymore. Check if your:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
```

is inside `<application>` tag.

Comment: Why? it still in docs
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/

Comment: FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize is deprecated.

Comment: i added the above `meta-data` in <application> inside androidManifest & my built was unsuccessful. It was successful before and I was getting an error on the server.

Comment: Man, U Just saved me. I was stuck from last 2 days

Answer (score 10):

There is a reason why `sdkInitialize()` is deprecated.

Go to your manifest file within the android folder and add following

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
      android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
```

After that append in your `strings.xml` file (res/values/strings.xml) the string entry:

```
<string name="facebook_app_id">APP_ID</string>
```

Close your Metro Builder and rebuild your Project using react-native run-android

Comment: still gives `The SDK has not been initialized, make sure to call FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize() first.` even if it is configured properly in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Killed the server and started again it worked.

Answer (score 5):

**Follow only 2 Step and your Facebook Sdk iw working in React Native**

```
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
              android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

    <string name="facebook_app_id">YOUR_APP_ID_HERE</string>
```

**Don't Need this  b'coz Its Deprecated Now**

```
  FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: how to get app id

Answer (score 5):

Seeing the responses listed in this question, the old way to initialize Facebook was:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

 @Override
 public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    // Initialize the SDK before executing any other operations,
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
   }
 }
```

But we can get the message:

> Facebook Sdk Has Not Been Initialized FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize()

`FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize()` now is deprecated.

Now (2021) Facebook initialization has changed, [**the Facebook initialization is automatically**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/).

1 Add the following to the dependencies {} section of your build.gradle (module: app) file to compile the latest version of the Facebook SDK for Android:

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:latest.release'
```

**Add Your Facebook App ID and Client Token**

Add your Facebook App ID and Client Token to your project's strings file and update your Android manifest:

1 Open your `/app/res/values/strings.xml` file.

2 Add a string element with the name attribute facebook_app_id and value as your Facebook App ID to the file. For example

```
<string name="facebook_app_id">Facebook App ID</string>
<string name="facebook_client_token">Facebook Client ID</string>
```

3 Open `/app/manifests/AndroidManifest.xml`

4 Add a uses-permission element to the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

5 Add a meta-data element to the application element:

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" ...>
    ...
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken" android:value="@string/facebook_client_token"/>
    ...
</application>
```

Comment: Note also that `facebook_client_token`has been added in the last months.

Comment: adding facebook_client_token did the trick for me

Answer (score 3):

After checking the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/) I found that they are asking to **initialize *FacebookSdk* in Application class `onCreate()` Method**.

**Snap code from Facebook doc:**

```
  public class MyApplication extends Application {
 // Updated your class body:
 @Override
 public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    // Initialize the SDK before executing any other operations,
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
   }
 }
```

Comment: this is now deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

My app was crashing because the ***Privacy Policy*** url was not provided in "Settings/Basic" in https://developers.facebook.com/. (in fact it was provided but I had to "Save changes" again. Seems a bug from Facebook).

The app was working fine and the error message `Facebook Sdk Has Not Been Initialized FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize()`disappeared. Hope this help.

Comment: Why the vote down? I struggled to find out that it came from the **_Privacy Policy_** and that it was not a coding issue.

Comment: I agree with Mike here. Most of the times the error is misleading.
For example, i got the error ```FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize() first``` while i am damn sure that i have done all the steps.
Finally figured out that, this line is not at all necessary but I was missing the facebook_client_token in strings.xml or in AndroidManifest.xml directly.
After that it worked well.
By looking at Mikes answer, it seems like even if i had solved it, if my situation is like Mikes', i probably would have got a hint from answer! 
Hence my upvote to Mike.

Answer (score 0):

Use Initialise Callback Constructor like this:

```
    Handler mHandler = new Handler();
            FacebookSdk.InitializeCallback initializeCallback = new FacebookSdk.InitializeCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onInitialized() {

                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            //UI Code Here
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
    //before setContentView()   
 FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),initializeCallback);
```

Answer (score 0):

If this helps anyone. For me I had to make this change

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:latest.release' // for FB login
```

the above line of code must be added to the END of the dependencies object and not anywhere in between.
This is in android/app/build.gradle  file

Answer (score 0):

For me, this issue arose due to a package in my application called react-native-fbsdk.
Please check your `package.json` file for the same.

I removed the package using `npm uninstall fbsdk` and rebuilt by app and it worked perfectly.

Hope this solution works for you!

Answer (score 0):

This might help someone. so till facebook SDK 13 i was using this for initializing the facebook SDK

```
<meta-data
            android: name="com.facebook.accountkit.ClientToken"
            android:value="@string/facebook_client_token" />
```

but now this **accountkit** changed to **sdk**

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken"
            android:value="@string/facebook_client_token" />
```

after this facebook SDK is initializing again.

Answer (score -1):

remove `android:exported=true` from AndroidManifest.xml and targetSdkVersion should be less than 31