# Error with android login button

Tags: android, facebook

I´m implementing a android login button, when I start the app I get the following message error.

> E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.droidsmile.opinions, PID: 31695
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.droidsmile.opinions/com.droidsmile.opinions.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton

And other line:

> Caused by: The SDK has not been initialized, make sure to call FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize() first.

Where can I call the method?

Thanks.

Comment: Please show your work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());` before `setContentView(R.layout.your_activity_layout);` as [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29605236/cant-get-location-and-email-using-facebook-api/29605975#29605975) states out. In case you need a complete facebook login example, check this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29605236/cant-get-location-and-email-using-facebook-api/29605975#29605975).

check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30213369/facebook-sdk-has-not-been-initilized).