# Android Facebook integration login exception in setContentView

Tags: android, facebook, exception

This is my MainActivity. The app is giving me a null pointer Exception at  set content view  and the app crashes please help.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.CallbackManager; 
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private LoginButton loginButton;
private TextView info;
private CallbackManager callbackManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);//here I get a nullpointerexception
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);
    loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            info.setText(
                    "User ID: "
                            + loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId()
                            + "\n" +
                            "Auth Token: "
                            + loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken()
            );
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            info.setText("Login attempt failed.");

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}}
```

Above is my MainActivity. The app is giving me a null pointer Exception at set contentView The error is not resolving I have tried various ways

```
 06-07 22:31:49.398 1020-1020/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                             Process: com.example.saranshagarwal.facebookintegration1, PID: 1020
                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.saranshagarwal.facebookintegration1/com.example.saranshagarwal.facebookintegration1.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                              Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                 at com.example.saranshagarwal.facebookintegration1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5318)
                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1090)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643) 
                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                              Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                 at com.example.saranshagarwal.facebookintegration1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23) 
                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5318) 
                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1090) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643) 
                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                              Caused by: The SDK has not been initialized, make sure to call FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize() first.
                                                 at com.facebook.internal.Validate.sdkInitialized(Validate.java:145)
                                                 at com.facebook.AccessTokenTracker.<init>(AccessTokenTracker.java:55)
                                                 at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton$2.<init>(LoginButton.java:563)
                                                 at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton.configureButton(LoginButton.java:563)
                                                 at com.facebook.FacebookButtonBase.<init>(FacebookButtonBase.java:69)
                                                 at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton.<init>(LoginButton.java:201)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                 at com.example.saranshagarwal.facebookintegration1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23) 
                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5318) 
                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1090) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643) 
                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is my Log cat

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.saranshagarwal.facebookintegration1">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />


</application>
```

This is my Manifest

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="16dp"
>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/info"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    />

<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/login_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    />
```

This is the activity_main.xml

Comment: can you post the log output of the crash?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook Sdk Has Not Been Initilized](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30213369/facebook-sdk-has-not-been-initilized)

Comment: post you xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line just above setContentView not after

```
 FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
```

As you are using facebook sdk login button in activity_main xml and this xml you do set in setContentView and FacebookSdk is not initialize yet. So this gives you a null pointer exception.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: who did downvote for my answer...Please tell me what is problem in my answer.