# FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize - call it once, or once per activity?

Tags: android, facebook

Do I need to put `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());` in every activity? Or just the first activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are asking to initialize it in Application class onCreate() Method.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
// Updated your class body:

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    // Initialize the SDK before executing any other operations,
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
}
```

[Link to the original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30213369/facebook-sdk-has-not-been-initilized)

Comment: but do I need to initialize it multiple times in different activities?