# Android - Facebook SDK 4.30 Initialization

Tags: android, facebook, android-fragments, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.x

I get the following error when trying to login by Facebook when using the latest SDK version which is 4.30:

> The SDK has not been initialized, make sure to call
>   `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize()`

Then the application crashes.

Although, in the official documentation it's supposed to be already auto initialized.

Note that `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize()` is deprecated now so it should not be called!

Error Log when not calling `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize()` :

```
  The SDK has not been initialized, make sure to call
 FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize() first.   at
 com.facebook.internal.Validate.sdkInitialized(Validate.java:143)   at
 com.facebook.login.LoginManager.<init>(LoginManager.java:79)    at
 com.facebook.login.LoginManager.getInstance(LoginManager.java:92)   
 at
 com.linkdev.tepdeal.login.LoginPresenter.loginWithFacebook(LoginPresenter.java:88)
 at
 com.linkdev.tepdeal.login.FragmentLogin.onClick(FragmentLogin.java:105)
 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637) at
 android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22433)    at
 android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)     at
 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) at
 android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) at
 android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6186) at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)  at
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
```

When forcing to call the deprecated `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize()` in the application on create the following error occurs:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
Lcom/facebook/common/R$layout;                    at
com.facebook.FacebookActivity.onCreate(FacebookActivity.java:77)    
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6684)    at
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
```

P.S:
 I get an error when trying to use the Facebook login button

> Error inflating class com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton

Comment: Add this line before button click FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize().

Comment: Post the full error log

Comment: @Shivan FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize()is deprecated

Comment: Your problem has already been solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30213369/facebook-sdk-has-not-been-initilized).

Comment: @gendkidesuka no it'haven't

Comment: For next one come to here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47463456/3304470

Answer (score 3):

Just a reminder, if one do define like this

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="1234"/>
```

Not what is required in the https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
```

They will get

> The SDK has not been initialized, make sure to call 
>   FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize()

I meet this scenario in Facebook Share SDK 4.31.0

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-share:4.31.0'
```

Comment: This worked for me, after trying different solutions for like 4 hours. Still, I don't get why setting the value directly doesn't work..

Answer (score 1):

This issue generally occurs when you forget to add the Facebook app id in the manifest file.

Follow these steps to make sure that you do not miss something.

[Facebook Login for Android - Quickstart](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android?sdk=maven)

Comment: I followed the steps from that guide and the Facebook app id is enlisted in the manifest

Comment: The initialization:

FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
should be done before setting the content view.

If you do:

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
before the initialization, the Facebook button won't be inflated into the activity.

Comment: FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext()) is deprecated and should not be called in the latest SDK