# The SDK has not been initialized, make sure to call FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize() first react native

Tags: android, react-native, android-facebook, fbsdk

I know this was asked before, but none of the solutions seem to help. I'm using first time Facebook SDK in my application.

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.spade;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
  @Override
  protected String getMainComponentName() {
    return "spade";
  }
}
```

MainApplication.java

```
package com.spade;   
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import io.invertase.firebase.RNFirebasePackage;
import io.invertase.firebase.notifications.RNFirebaseNotificationsPackage;
import com.th3rdwave.safeareacontext.SafeAreaContextPackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.List;
import com.oblador.vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage;
import io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseMessagingPackage;
    
public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {
 List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
            new VectorIconsPackage();
            new RNFirebaseNotificationsPackage();
            new RNFirebaseMessagingPackage();

          return packages;
}
```

What I have done wrong out there ? I don't understand the issue as I was new in react native

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30213369/facebook-sdk-has-not-been-initialized-facebooksdk-sdkinitialize

Comment: I think the error message is pretty clear: you're not calling `sdkInitialize()`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have to [add](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android) a new hash key because I changed environment

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).