# Facebook Sdk crash Webview login

Tags: android, facebook, webview

I am using the Facebook Sdk 4.1.0 as dependency in my app. To do login, I follow this instructions:  [Can't get location and email using Facebook API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29605236/cant-get-location-and-email-using-facebook-api/29605975#29605975)

And login works fine if the Facebook apps is installed in the device but if the Facebook app is not installed (login goes throw a webview created by facebook) then my app crash if the user click on the button login inside the webview:

[image]

And if the user press de Log in button the app crash inmediatly:

> android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window --
>   token null is not for an application at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:559) at
>   android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:269)
>   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
>   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:289) at
>   android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:951) at
>   com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter.onSavePassword(WebViewContentsClientAdapter.java:752)
>   at
>   com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.AwContentsClientCallbackHelper$1.handleMessage(AwContentsClientCallbackHelper.java:157)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5271) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:851)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:667) at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Can you put your code of webview dialog class? You are using wrong context to show dialog thats the reason the null error is coming.

Comment: I don't have any webview. The webview is launched by Facebook because the facebook app is not installed in the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the Facebook Sdk to 4.0 instead of 4.1 and now is working. Unbelievable.

Answer (score 0):

there was an issue with you permissions you are passing you have to debug the code
you can test it by changing your permissions request...

Comment: What permissions do you mean? At the facebook developer web or in the code? Maybe the `loginButton.setReadPermissions(permissionNeeds);` ?