# location.getLatitude() throws NullPointerException android

Tags: android, location

I'm trying to get the current latitude and longitude coordinates.

**my code**

```
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_LOW);
    String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);

    if (location != null) {
        onLocationChanged(location);
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 20000, 0, this);

    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
```

**error message**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{conic.com.restaurant/conic.com.restaurant.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at conic.com.restaurant.MainActivity.displayListView(MainActivity.java:121)
            at conic.com.restaurant.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:50)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here are the manifest declarations
**manifest declarations**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

> double latitude = location.getLatitude(); is in line number 121

Hope you can help me.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: both are declared in manifest

Comment: Location does not require Internet. I think you should know this.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17519198/how-to-get-the-current-location-latitude-and-longitude-in-android

Comment: Now Google has introduced the Fused Location API. It is so efficient than this previous way you are using. Refer this link. [Link](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html)

Answer (score 2):

Before getting Latitude and Longitude, check:

```
if(location!=null){
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use NETWORK_PROVIDER to get location because many times GPS will give null latitude and longitude

```
m_locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,0,0, this);
    m_location = m_locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

Add below permissions in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
double longitude = location.getLongitude();
double latitude = location.getLatitude();

lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 10, locationListener);
```