# Look if current location is near marker

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I have a Google Maps API Activity and want the markes only to be clickable if the user is in a certain radius to them.
How is the best way to do this?
This is how I set my markers:

```
Marker marker1 = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(49.793012, 9.926201))
            .title(getString(R.string.Title1))
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker)));
    Marker marker2 = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(49.792742, 9.939118))
            .title(getString(R.string.Title2))
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker)));
    Marker marker3 = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(49.793349, 9.932558))
            .title(getString(R.string.Title3))
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker)));
```

Solution code:

```
LatLng markerPosition = marker.getPosition();
myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
Location markerLoc = new Location("marker");
markerLoc.setLatitude(markerPosition.latitude);
markerLoc.setLongitude(markerPosition.longitude);
float meters = myLocation.distanceTo(markerLoc);
```

Comment: Did you solve your problem? Have you cheked my answer?

Comment: I still had problems comparing the two locations. I did it this way now:
`LatLng markerPosition = marker.getPosition();
                myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
Location markerLoc = new Location("marker");
markerLoc.setLatitude(markerPosition.latitude);
markerLoc.setLongitude(markerPosition.longitude);
float meters = myLocation.distanceTo(markerLoc);`

Comment: Edit your quesiton with your code

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `LatLng` of the markers by `marker.getPosition()`; then you can compare it with the `CurrentLocation`. To do this, you can check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17519198/how-to-get-the-current-location-latitude-and-longitude-in-android), and next you can make `clickable` or `notclickable` a marker as follows:

```
getMap().setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        onMapClick(marker.getPosition());
        return true;
    }
});
```

If you return `true` for the function, it means that you've accepted the occurred click event on your `marker`; otherwise, you've not accepted it.

Moreover, you can do it with:

`MarkerOptions.clickable` and `Marker.setClickable`.

This is just a guide who how I would do what you want. hope it helps. :)