# how to set my google Map app to be show my current location as default?

Tags: android, api, google-maps, dictionary

so that I don't have to search, when I on the app, it will point to my current location

this is my code, I am using a google Map API at the moment.

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        LatLng hcmus = new LatLng(10.762963, 106.682394);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(hcmus, 18));
        originMarkers.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .title("Đại học Khoa học tự nhiên")
                .position(hcmus)));

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
```

Comment: I don't understand the solution

Comment: Try this [similar thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17519198/how-to-get-the-current-location-latitude-and-longitude-in-android).