# Can we get latitude longitude without using location api or google api

Tags: android, location, wifi, latitude-longitude

I want to get latitude and longitude without using android `Location Service` and `Google Api`.
So Is there any way to get latitude and longitude from connected `wifi` router ?

Answer (score 2):

First of all get the IP Address using the following code:

```
 public String getIpAddr() {
   WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
   WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
   int ip = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();

   String ipString = String.format("%d.%d.%d.%d", (ip & 0xff), (ip >> 8 & 0xff), (ip >> 16 & 0xff), (ip >> 24 & 0xff));
   return ipString;
}
```

Please Note: You need to add android.permission.INTERNET and android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE in your AndroidManifest.xml as  to access the code.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

After this use some 3rd party web service which gives you langitude and latitude by providing IP. Example : http://www.geoipservice.asmx/GetGeoIP?IPAddress= (PASS IP AS STRING)

Hope you got your answer!!!

Comment: Thanks for reply .Let me check this

Comment: getting below error when trying to use above web service `java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "www.geoipservice.asmx": No address associated with hostname`

Comment: Try this webservice http://ip-api.com/json/172.217.4.227 .. Use your IP instead of Google's .. ;) ..

Comment: Thanks. I have tried above webservice but in response am getting below response `{"message":"private range","query":"My IP Address","status":"fail"}
`     .What does mean by **private range**

Comment: See this works for me ... [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxnXj5S9SPTGX1AyWnFoMjZ2YlE)

Comment: Yes Its working with google IP ,but when i used mine IP address instead of google then its saying that **private range** .I think its the problem of wifi. Can you elaborate more the meaning of **private range** that when this comes

Comment: @Android Do vote up and mark this as correct answer if it worked for you .. :)

Comment: These are Private IP ranges 192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255
172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255
10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255 Visit [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) for more info on Private IPs

Comment: Create a free account on [Hostinger](http://www.hostinger.in/) or any similar and deploy your code there... And use the IP provided by Hostinger .. :) IF USING A WEBSERVICE ... or else use [Appetize](https://appetize.io/) to debug you Android App ... :)

Comment: I am developing an android app .And phone is connected with office wifi , Finaaly i'm calling web service provided by you

Comment: Go to Wi-Fi Setting in your phone... Open the Menu and Go to Advanced and check the IP Address there .. or if any trouble doing this download an app to find your current IP ...

Comment: Hey i am able to find IP address ,IP address is not the problem ,I think Problem is that my wifi is not allowing to find the location.Or the problem may be the web service `ip-api.com/json/172.217.4.227` is not able to access my wifi IP address

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

[code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17519248/5612089)

This will give you longitude and latitude

Comment: As i have mentioned in question that without using android `Location Service`

Comment: @Android I think you can't get it without `Location Service`