# Not able to open directions in google map in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I have one screen in app which shows address. Now I want to open google when while click on that address. And it have to show directions from current location to that address.

//code in app

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=28.5600697,77.2695753"));
            startActivity(intent);
```

but it is not opening location only processing.

Comment: How ? @IbrahimAli

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=28.5600697,77.2695753"));
            startActivity(intent);
```

and please let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. this will Suppress chooser dialog when calling Google map using intent

```
                    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+Latitude+","+Longitude+"&daddr="+latitude+","+longitude));
                    intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
                    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Not working and I also want that this must show from current location

Comment: whats the issue?

Comment: what to be use in saddr ?

Comment: replace with your values

Comment: which values that I want to know.I am adding values of daddr of that location where I want to navigate but what values in saddr

Comment: saddr will be your current location's lat and long

Comment: how to get current lat and long ?

Comment: [how to get current lat and long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17519198/how-to-get-the-current-location-latitude-and-longitude-in-android)

Comment: is it possible that instead of latitude and longitude I can add only in daddr?

Comment: Now thats not possible

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 float storeLatitude = Float.parseFloat(storeList.latitude + "");
 float storeLongitude = Float.parseFloat(storeList.longitude + "");

 String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=%f,%f (%s)", storeLatitude, storeLongitude, "Store Address");
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
 intent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
 startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to fetch user's current Latitude and Longitude than use following :

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
    Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + mUserLatitude + ", " + mUserLongitude +
   "&daddr=" + lat + ", " + lon));
    startActivity(intent);
```

Where lat , lon is destination Latitude and Longitude resepectively.