# Does fused location api charges money when request exceeds 1000

Tags: android, google-maps, fusedlocationproviderapi

I am currently using Fused Location API for android to get latitude and longitude of my device. What i want to know is does google charge money for fused location api too?
Actually the app should give 24 hrs update of its location to the server.

Comment: This is an off topic question . You should first check [Google quota](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/usage) before posting question here.

Comment: But I have to get only latitude and longitude in my app. I dont want to use places api

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17519248/4168607) maybe help.

Comment: But i dont want to use gps tracker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Google doesn't charge you anything for using `FusedLocationProvider`. It is free of cost. If you just want to get GPS location, it is free. If you use other APIs from Google Play Service then you might come under quota limit.

Comment: thank you very much...If i wan to show simple map and make marker move as per location update than does it come under quota limit?

Comment: If your app is gonna be free, then there is no limit on Google Maps API for Android. https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/

Comment: @NinjaCoder ,any idea if it's still free now in 2019? In my app, I need to update the marker's location every 20 seconds using FusedLocationProviderClient. There's gonna be thousands of requests per month. Thanks!