# Unable to Get Coordinates from Location Service on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, geolocation, locationmanager

I am new to Android Studio and am trying to retrieve the co-ordinates of an Android device using Location Service.

I have all the relevant permissions enabled in the manifest (the Coarse and Fine locations, and the Internet).

In my MainActivity.java, I have the following. However, when I run it in Android Studio, for the 3 test cases I have in the activity, the TextView **ShowLocation** always become "Something else", meaning that it went to the third case where location is null (no location detected?) but permission has been granted properly.

What am I doing wrong here? Is it because I could not test Location Service in Android Studio? How can I test and obtain co-ordinate values in an Android application using Android Studio?

A snippet of **MainActivity.java**

```
     locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION);
                }

                Location loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                if (loc != null) {
                    latitude = String.valueOf(loc.getLatitude());
                    showLocation.setText("Latitude" + latitude);
                }

                else {

                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        showLocation.setText("No GPS Permission granted");
                   
                    } else
                        showLocation.setText("Something else");
                }
```

Comment: Have your declared ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION in manifest.xml file ?

Comment: @NRUSINGHAMOHARANA Yup, that has been declared in the manifest file.

Comment: did you try with `Location loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);` but you need to add network permission in the manifest

Comment: please visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17519198/how-to-get-the-current-location-latitude-and-longitude-in-android

Comment: The `getLastKnownLocation()` just returns the last known location (hence the name) if one exists. It may also return `null`. It doesn't power up the GPS module and fetch a fresh up-to-date location. For that you need to request location updates. And GPS won't work indoors.

Comment: @ShayKin I have tried `NETWORK_PROVIDER` as well, still seemed to have the same problem.

@MarkusKauppinen, any insight on how to power up to GPS module?

Comment: [https://developer.android.com/training/location/request-updates](https://developer.android.com/training/location/request-updates)