# Android Geocoder returns null address list

Tags: android

Hi I have written a code to get addresses in new york and the code as follows.

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        txtLocationView.setText("Longitudes: "
                + String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()) + "Latitudes:"
                + String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
        Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.ENGLISH);

        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(
                    location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 10);

            String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
            String city = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
            String country = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);
            txtAddressView.setText("Address:"  + addresses);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

But tis has returned a null Address list . um passing locaion correctly . What can possibly go wrong?

Comment: See if [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472313/android-reverse-geocoding-getfromlocation) helps you.

Comment: wow nice to see you here :) coincident :)

Comment: Haha yeah! Coincident indeed! Just came across your question while I was browsing through.

Comment: The javadoc of getFromLocation states that it "Returns null or empty list if no matches were found or there is no backend service available."  So guard against it.

Comment: I passed geo location of new york