# Displaying location (address) in another activity class in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to display user's location in another class from my location class.

Here's my location class that is getting location and resolving address of the user. Please notice the getAddressLine method in the following class as I wanna display the address line in another class.

**MyLocation.Java**

```html
package miniandroid.com.services;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import miniandroid.com.R;

/**
 * Create this Class from tutorial :
 * http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial
 *
 * For Geocoder read this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472313/android-reverse-geocoding-getfromlocation
 *
 */

public class MyLocation extends Service implements LocationListener {

    // Get Class Name
    private static String TAG = MyLocation.class.getName();

    private Context mContext;

    // flag for GPS Status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    // flag for GPS Tracking is enabled
    boolean isGPSTrackingEnabled = false;

    Location location;
    public double latitude;
    public double longitude;

    // How many Geocoder should return our GPSTracker
    int geocoderMaxResults = 1;

    // The minimum distance to change updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 300; // 300 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 2; // 3 hours

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    // Store LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER or LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER information
    private String provider_info;

    public MyLocation(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public MyLocation()
    {

    }


    /**
     * Try to get my current location by GPS or Network Provider
     */
    public void getLocation() {

        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            //getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            //getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            // Try to get location if you GPS Service is enabled
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                this.isGPSTrackingEnabled = true;

                Log.d(TAG, "Application use GPS Service");

                /*
                 * This provider determines location using
                 * satellites. Depending on conditions, this provider may take a while to return
                 * a location fix.
                 */

                provider_info = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;

            } else if (isNetworkEnabled) { // Try to get location if you Network Service is enabled
                this.isGPSTrackingEnabled = true;

                Log.d(TAG, "Application use Network State to get GPS coordinates");

                /*
                 * This provider determines location based on
                 * availability of cell tower and WiFi access points. Results are retrieved
                 * by means of a network lookup.
                 */
                provider_info = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;

            }

            // Application can use GPS or Network Provider
            if (!provider_info.isEmpty()) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                    return;
                }
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        provider_info,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,
                        this
                );

                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider_info);
                    updateGPSCoordinates();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "Impossible to connect to LocationManager", e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Update GPSTracker latitude and longitude
     */
    public void updateGPSCoordinates() {
        if (location != null) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();

            String location = latitude + "," + longitude;
            SharedPreferences prefsy = getSharedPreferences("emood_veriif", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefsy.edit();
            editor.putString("MapFirst", location);
            editor.commit();
        }
    }

    /**
     * GPSTracker latitude getter and setter
     * @return latitude
     */
    public double getLatitude() {
        if (location != null) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * GPSTracker longitude getter and setter
     * @return
     */
    public double getLongitude() {
        if (location != null) {
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * GPSTracker isGPSTrackingEnabled getter.
     * Check GPS/wifi is enabled
     */
    public boolean getIsGPSTrackingEnabled() {

        return this.isGPSTrackingEnabled;
    }

    /**
     * Stop using GPS listener
     * Calling this method will stop using GPS in your app
     */
    public void stopUsingGPS() {
        if (locationManager != null) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            locationManager.removeUpdates(MyLocation.this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Function to show settings alert dialog
     */
    public void showSettingsAlert() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        //Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("Location access");

        //Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("Select settings to enable location access.");

        //On Pressing Setting button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.action_settings, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        //On pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Get list of address by latitude and longitude
     * @return null or List<Address>
     */
    public List<Address> getGeocoderAddress(Context context) {
        if (location != null) {

            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.ENGLISH);

            try {
                /**
                 * Geocoder.getFromLocation - Returns an array of Addresses
                 * that are known to describe the area immediately surrounding the given latitude and longitude.
                 */
                List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, this.geocoderMaxResults);

                return addresses;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(TAG, "Impossible to connect to Geocoder", e);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Try to get AddressLine
     * @return null or addressLine
     */
    public String getAddressLine(Context context) {
        List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);

        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            String addressLine = address.getAddressLine(0);

            return addressLine;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Try to get Locality
     * @return null or locality
     */
    public String getLocality(Context context) {
        List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);

        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            String locality = address.getLocality();

            return locality;
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Try to get Postal Code
     * @return null or postalCode
     */
    public String getPostalCode(Context context) {
        List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);

        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            String postalCode = address.getPostalCode();

            return postalCode;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Try to get CountryName
     * @return null or postalCode
     */
    public String getCountryName(Context context) {
        List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);
        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            String countryName = address.getCountryName();

            return countryName;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        startService(new Intent(this,TrackMeService.class));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

However, I am trying to class this in my **HomeActivity.Java**.

```html
package miniandroid.com.activities;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import miniandroid.com.R;
import miniandroid.com.helpers.UserPreference;
import miniandroid.com.services.LocationService;
import miniandroid.com.services.MyLocation;

public class HomeActivity extends Activity {
    private static TextView hometext;
    UserPreference userPreference;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.homepage);
        hometext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.homepagetxt);
        userPreference = new UserPreference(this);
        setTitle("sMood - " + userPreference.getUserName());
        hometext.setText("Hello " + userPreference.getUserName() + "!" + "\nYour current location is:" + "I wanna display address here" );
        MyLocation gpsTracker = new MyLocation(this);
        if (gpsTracker.getIsGPSTrackingEnabled()) {

            String stringLongitude = String.valueOf(gpsTracker.longitude);
            String stringLatitude = String.valueOf(gpsTracker.latitude);
            String location = stringLatitude + "," + stringLongitude;
            SharedPreferences prefsy = getSharedPreferences("emood_veriif", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefsy.edit();
            editor.putString("MapFirst", location);
            editor.commit();
        } else {
            gpsTracker.showSettingsAlert();
        }

        startService(new Intent(this, LocationService.class));
    }


}
```

I have been trying to just get the getAddressLine method from the MyLocation.Java, but it is not working for me.

any help or input is highly appreciate, I have been working on this from days.