# Using geocoder in ListView

Tags: android

I have an app that displays a ListView with Cards, and these cards have already the latitude and longitude information. I need to show in each card the address of that location. First i was calling Geocoder directly in each card and it really works, but the app takes a long time to answer. So I read the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html) and it recommends:

> you should not call it from the main, user interface (UI) thread of
>   your app

So it recommends to create a service and use the Geocoder there. The problem is that i can't implement the suggested code to each card (elements of the ListView). My code is the following. I have a **FeaturesFragment**:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.features_layout, container, false);

        // Used to operate the database
        PhotoDAO photoDAO = new PhotoDAO(getActivity());
        //Receives the cursor with the result of the search
        final Cursor cursor = photoDAO.searchAll();

        // list that shows the items. Cards are set into the adapter
        ListView listView = (ListView) myView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        PhotoAdapter adapter = new PhotoAdapter(getActivity(), cursor);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                String description = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PhotoContract.PhotoEntry.COLUMN_PHOTO_DESCRIPTION));
                String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PhotoContract.PhotoEntry.COLUMN_PHOTO_PATH));
                Long id_photo = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PhotoContract.PhotoEntry._ID));

                Log.v(TAG, path);
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), PhotoDescriptionActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("id", id_photo);
                i.putExtra("path", path);
                i.putExtra("description", description);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        return myView;
    }
```

I'm using a custon CursorAdapter called **PhotoAdapter** that is:
*(the commented part is the old geocoder code)*

```
@Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        // First, select the category to show on the card
        int id_cat = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PhotoEntry.COLUMN_ID_CATEGORY));
        CategoryDAO categoryDAO = new CategoryDAO(context);
        Category category = categoryDAO.search(String.valueOf(id_cat));

        // Get the object located at this position in the list
        String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PhotoEntry.COLUMN_PHOTO_PATH));
        String description = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PhotoEntry.COLUMN_PHOTO_DESCRIPTION));
        String time = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PhotoEntry.COLUMN_PHOTO_TIME));
        Double latitude = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PhotoEntry.COLUMN_PHOTO_LATITUDE));
        Double longitude = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PhotoEntry.COLUMN_PHOTO_LONGITUDE));
        Date dt = FormatDateTimeUtil.stringToDate(time, FormatDateTimeUtil.FORMAT_DATE);

        TextView txtCategory = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_category);
        ImageView imageResource = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.photo_card);
        ExpandableTextView txtDescription = (ExpandableTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.expand_text_view);
        TextView txtTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_time);
        TextView txtCity = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_city);

        String cidade;
        String estado;
        String pais;

        /*Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            List<Address> add = gcd.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);

            if (add.size() > 0) {
                cidade = add.get(0).getLocality();
                estado = add.get(0).getAdminArea();
                pais = add.get(0).getCountryName();

                txtCity.setText(cidade+", "+estado+". "+pais);
            } else {
                txtCity.setText(R.string.location_unknown);
            }


        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "It wasn't possible to get location");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/

        //controls the heap to load images, preventing a memory overload
        Glide.with(context).load(path).into(imageResource);
        txtDescription.setText(description);

        txtTime.setText(FormatDateTimeUtil.dateToString(dt));

        txtCategory.setText(category.getDescription());

    }
```

So how can I use the *service* in each element of the ListView? Or is there some other way to get these locations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by using a GeocoderHandler and other thread like this:

**PhotoAdapter**

```
public void bindView(View view, Context ctx, Cursor cursor) {

    final Context context = ctx;

    appLocationService = new AppLocationService(
            context);

    // First, select the category to show on the card
    int id_cat = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PhotoEntry.COLUMN_ID_CATEGORY));
    CategoryDAO categoryDAO = new CategoryDAO(context);
    Category category = categoryDAO.search(String.valueOf(id_cat));

    // Get the object located at this position in the list
    final String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PhotoEntry._ID));
    final String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PhotoEntry.COLUMN_PHOTO_PATH));
    final String description = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PhotoEntry.COLUMN_PHOTO_DESCRIPTION));
    final String time = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PhotoEntry.COLUMN_PHOTO_TIME));
    final Double latitude = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PhotoEntry.COLUMN_PHOTO_LATITUDE));
    final Double longitude = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PhotoEntry.COLUMN_PHOTO_LONGITUDE));

    Date dt = FormatDateTimeUtil.stringToDate(time, FormatDateTimeUtil.FORMAT_DATE);

    TextView txtCategory = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_category);
    ImageView imageResource = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.photo_card);
    ExpandableTextView txtDescription = (ExpandableTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.expand_text_view);
    TextView txtTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_time);
    txtCity = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_city);

    //controls the heap to load images, preventing a memory overload
    Glide.with(context).load(path).into(imageResource);
    txtDescription.setText(description);
    txtTime.setText(FormatDateTimeUtil.dateToString(dt));
    txtCategory.setText(category.getDescription());

    LocationAddress locationAddress = new LocationAddress();
    locationAddress.getAddressFromLocation(latitude, longitude,
            getApplicationContext(), new GeocoderHandler());


    imageResource.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), PhotoDescriptionActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("id", id);
            i.putExtra("path", path);
            i.putExtra("description", description);
            v.getContext().startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}

private class GeocoderHandler extends Handler {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) {
        String locationAddress;
        switch (message.what) {
            case 1:
                Bundle bundle = message.getData();
                locationAddress = bundle.getString("address");
                break;
            default:
                locationAddress = null;
        }
        txtCity.setText(locationAddress);
    }
}
```

In my **FeaturesFragment** I just removed the *clicklistener* because it had to be moved to PhotoAdapter. 
Using the GeocoderHandler for each card the location is loaded in background, not hindering the user interface. As reference, i used the answer of EricLarch in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472313/android-reverse-geocoding-getfromlocation)