# How to reverse geocoding using gms?

Tags: android, google-maps

I noticed that there exists the GMSGeocoder for reverse geocoding for iOS, but not found the similarity in Google play service.

Of course, I can use the [Geocoder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) in the Android Location api, or, there also a way for reverse geocoding using [http request](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) for this. but with the applied API key, I did find the corresponding XXGeocoder in GMS for Android in Google play service.

Did I miss it?

Answer (score 0):

Seems the android [Geocoder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) could do the work good enough.

From this [ariticle](https://developer.zebra.com/community/android/android-forums/android-blogs/blog/2017/08/07/location-apis-available-on-gms-aosp-devices):

> The Android Geocoder API is also only available on GMS devices with location services although it does not depend on the GoogleApiClient like Geofencing and Activity Recognition.  The Geocoder class offers both geocoding and reverse geocoding meaning it will return a lat / long based on an address and vice-versa.  In my experience the API provides very accurate results and it has clear benefits to package delivery use cases.

Answer (score 0):

This might fulfill your question [Android: Reverse geocoding - getFromLocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472313/android-reverse-geocoding-getfromlocation)

I've used it, and you have to specify how many matching address you want. The first address be accurate most of the times, but at times it can be a bit off the current address, just so you know