# How to get address from current location from setMyLocationEnabled(true);

Tags: java, android, google-maps, reverse-geocoding

In my project I used **Google Maps Activity** and to get the user's current location I used `setMyLocationEnabled(this);` method to get the location. And when I tried to fetch the latitude and longitude from that location it throws a error says null object reference.

I looked for many videos in YouTube and examined many questions in stack overflow and blogs but I can't find the proper code to be done to do that. Some use deprecated methods and some go way beyond the topic.

So all I want is to do the reverse geo coding to get the address from my location and also add a marker at that point.

Help me guide what to do and how to obtain that I'm stuck with that from past 4 days.

Comment: You should post the stacktrace.

Comment: Stacktrace just throws a messages like attempt to income Virtual method on a null object reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverse Geocoding is what you are looking for. **Geocoder** class can be used
Look at this [Android: Reverse geocoding - getFromLocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472313/android-reverse-geocoding-getfromlocation)

It will give you idea of using reverse geocoding

Answer (score 0):

You can use [getFromLocation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocation(double,%20double,%20int)) from [Geocoder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html).

Sample code.

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
try {
    List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(
            latitude, longitude, 1);
    if (addressList != null && addressList.size() > 0) {
        Address address = addressList.get(0);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
            sb.append(address.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
        }
        sb.append(address.getLocality()).append("\n");
        sb.append(address.getPostalCode()).append("\n");
        sb.append(address.getCountryName());
        String result = sb.toString();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Unable connect to Geocoder", e);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but the code hasn't worked it gives me a error saying null pointer exception.